# Visual Studio Code not suggesting keywords for Unity like Transform, Physics and Vector3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am trying to learn Unity3d game development and would really appreciate some help here...

My issue is VS Code is not suggesting keywords like `RigidBody`, `Vector3`, `Transform`, `Physics`, `LayerMask`, if i type `Transform`, it highlights other suggestions such as `OnTransformChildrenChanged()` or `OnTransformParentChanged()` but not the `Transform`.

Any Help is appreciated

[image]

- just downloaded Visual Studio Code and the extensions needed to work with Unity3d.
- I also have Unity3d's code editor set to Visual Studio Code via Preferences -> External Tools -> External Tool Editor.
- Tried Reimport All, opening code from unity, Assets>open C# Project.
- installed .net 4.7.1 and the new versions too.
- I have watched multiple tutorials and downloaded multiple extensions for unity tools in VSCode.

still no fix to the Intellisense.

Comment: following microsoft instructions results in success.. Id suggest you have missed a step

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Everyone who tried to help, but at the end I couldn't get the fix for VScode instead I downloaded the latest VS community version with .Net 4.7.1 developer pack.

1. When installing VS community make sure to check the Unity code
   installer and other files your think you need.
2. After installation go to
   `Unity>Edit>Preferences>ExternalTool>ExternalScriptEditor>`select
   `MS VisualStudio 2022` or the one you installed and then click
   `Regenrate project files`.
3. After that click `Assets> Open C# Project`

For me this worked and the editor suggests keywords like `transform`, `Vector3`.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this doc and it works well.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity.
You might have missed this step:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure to install Visual Studio Code Editor in Package Manager.
Go to Unity Registry and type " Visual Studio Code Editor" and install it or update it
Worked for me because for some  reason Unity deleted my vs code Editor.

and I after doing this go to Edit > Preferences > External Tools > External Script Editor > Visual Studio Code

then click on one of the scripts in the project and you are good to go!

if you still have problems please tell me or check this link  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity